# Just That Middle Term is a Direct Sum of Extremes Does Not Mean the Sequence is Exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

> Does there exist a short exact sequence of the form $$0\to \mathbf Z\to \mathbf Z\oplus (\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z) \to \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\to 0$$
>   which does not split?

(Note: Don Alejo provided a link which answered part of my earlier question, which merely asked for the existence of a non-split exact sequence of the form $0\to A\to A\oplus C\to C\to 0$.)

Comment: This question has been asked several times here, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980432/
I think for finitely generated abelian groups, such a counterexample does not exist.

Comment: When I've closed this as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135444/a-nonsplit-short-exact-sequence-of-abelian-groups-with-b-cong-a-oplus-c I've read that thread (while those who voted for reopening and the OP certainly don't) and found two answers which prove that such a sequence can't exist.

Comment: @user26857 I apologize for not noticing the relevant answers. Is it possible that you mark this as a duplicate again? Thanks.